# How to load dicom from DCM4CHEE in cornerstone?

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

I am using cornerstone-wado-image-loader to display the dicom of the server using dcm4chee.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cornerstone-wado-image-loader

I have followed and read the documentation to obtain the DCM4CHEE dicom
Here an example

```
Dicomweb: http: // localhost: 3333 / wado? RequestType = WADO & studyUID = 1.3.6.1.4.1.25403.166563008443.5076.20120418075541.1 & seriesUID = 1.3.6.1.4.1.25403.166563008443.5076.20120418075541.2 & objectUID = 1.3.6.1.4.1.25403.166563008443.5076.20120418075557. 1 & contentType = application% 2Fdicom & transferSyntax = 1.2.840.10008.1.2.1
```

But I have doubt in how I am doing this is my code

```
Dicomweb: Http: // localhost: 8080 / dcm4chee-web3 / wado? RequestType = WADO & studyUID = 1.2.840.113619.2.134.1762680268.232 & seriesUID = 1.2.840.113619.2.134.1762680288.2032.1122564926.253 & objectUID = 1.2.840.113619.2.134.1762680288.2032.1122564926.265 & contentType = Application% 2Fdicom & transferSyntax = 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.91
```

I am using localhost: 8080 / dcm4chee / since that is the port that dcm4chee uses and the project I am doing uses port 3000, but I'm not sure if the url is correct, depending on the browser the url returns well with a status 200, but still I can not see the dicom, it is wrong the way the url is or I'm missing some configuration? please I need help

I'm sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the dcm4chee-web3 from your address:

```
http://localhost:8080/wado?requestType=WADO&studyUID...
```

You can check the format by viewing an image in DCM4CHEE, right-clicking on the image and selecting 'Copy Image Address,' and then pasting it into your browser location.

Comment: I can not get anything to remove dcm4chee-web3
And I can not see the dicom of dcm4chee, I think there is something wrong in how I do the reference in the url, I need help :(

Comment: I'm afraid I am misunderstanding your issue. Perhaps you can post the relevant code that is not working.